# argparse: how to configure multiple choice, multiple value, optional argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to set up an argument that accepts one or more values from a given list of choices, but is not obligatory. I'm trying this (with a couple of variants that also don't work as expected):

```
parser.add_argument("FLAGS", nargs='*', choices=["X","Y","Z","ALL"])
```

I expect to get a list of values from the list of choices, or an empty list if nothing was given (that, I think, should be enforced by `nargs='*'`). But regardless of whether I add `default=""` or not, when I don't pass any argument it fails with:

```
error: argument FLAGS: invalid choice: []
```

How to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably doesn't fit your needs, but you can do it easily with an option like `--flags`.

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--flags",
    nargs='*',
    default=[],  # Instead of "None"
    choices=["X", "Y", "Z", "ALL"])

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

```
$ tmp.py
Namespace(flags=[])

$ tmp.py --flags
Namespace(flags=[])

$ tmp.py --flags X
Namespace(flags=['X'])

$ tmp.py --flags X Z
Namespace(flags=['X', 'Z'])

$ tmp.py --flags foobar
usage: tmp.py [-h] [--flags [{X,Y,Z,ALL} ...]]
tmp.py: error: argument --flags: invalid choice: 'foobar' (choose from 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'ALL')

$ tmp.py --help
usage: tmp.py [-h] [--flags [{X,Y,Z,ALL} ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --flags [{X,Y,Z,ALL} ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

A positional '*' gets some special handling.  Its `nargs` is satisfied with an empty list (nothing).  It's always handled.  What does it mean to check an empty list of strings against the `choices`?

So the `get_values()` method does:

```
    # when nargs='*' on a positional, if there were no command-line
    # args, use the default if it is anything other than None
    elif (not arg_strings and action.nargs == ZERO_OR_MORE and
          not action.option_strings):
        if action.default is not None:
            value = action.default
        else:
            value = arg_strings
        self._check_value(action, value)
```

where `_check_value` tests if `value` is in the `choices`.

Such a positional is best used with a valid `default`.

```
In [729]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [730]: a=p.add_argument("FLAGS", nargs='*', choices=["X","Y","Z","ALL"])
In [731]: p.parse_args([])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [{X,Y,Z,ALL} [{X,Y,Z,ALL} ...]]
ipython3: error: argument FLAGS: invalid choice: [] (choose from 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'ALL')
...
```

Testing an empty list against `choices` fails:

```
In [732]: a.choices
Out[732]: ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'ALL']
In [733]: [] in a.choices
Out[733]: False
In [734]: 'X' in a.choices
Out[734]: True
```

If we set a valid default:

```
In [735]: a.default='X'
In [736]: p.parse_args([])
Out[736]: Namespace(FLAGS='X')
```

This behavior is part of what allows us to use such a positional in a `mutually_exclusive_group`.

If you don't want to specify a valid default, then changing this to a flagged argument avoids the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer, but do you know WHY argparse takes such a strange approach? If a positional parameter is configured with `nargs=0`, and if the end user supplies zero arguments, why run the non-existent arguments through the choices-validation machinery at all? Is there a compelling reason for the library to have this counter-intuitive implementation? And, secondarily, why are flag parameters with the same settings (`nargs=0`, plus `choices`) handled differently (ie, correctly, at least under my intuition)?

Comment: Also, I've seen enough expert-level argparse answers from you that I wondered whether you have worked on the argparse code base? I ask because I was curious if you had any warnings about what might be a viable workaround for my use case. Here's my configuration for a positional: `parser.add_argument('x', nargs = '*', choices = X_CHOICES + [[]])`. Since a user would never be able to supply an actual Python list on the command-line, I assume there won't be any unwanted side effects. But please let me know if you see a flaw in this workaround.

Comment: The handling of `choices` occurs in the `get_values` method I quoted from.  It does different things based largely on the `nargs` value.  The comments explain a bit of why.  Mostly the code is written to handle the most obvious cases, while edge cases tend not to get special handling.  Some behavior is more of a 'feature' than an intended thing.  If a 'feature/bug' hasn't caused problems for most users over the past 20 years it probably won't be changed now.  @FMc.

Comment: @FMc, did you reall mean `nargs=0` with `positional`.  That doesn't make much sense, since it will allways be `seen` (no input from the user is needed or possible).  `choices` wouldn't make sense with it either.

Comment: @FMc, at one time I tried to follow all bug/iissues, wrote many comments, and contributed some solutions (`push`).  I haven't done as much since the repository was moved to github.  Still probably know the code as well as anyone, and am keely aware of the difficulty of making changes without harming backwards compatibility.

Comment: @FMc, I don't know off hand what including the empty list is `choices` would do.  I'd have to test it, and maybe examine the code.  Keep in mind that the test for `choices` is a simple `in`.  `choices` is intended for a smalll list.  Anything too long or fancy can mess up the `help` or `error` display.  Some times it's better to put such tests in the `type` function, or wait until after parsing to make such tests.  You don't get extra points for making `argparse` do all the checking.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail. And, yes, `nargs=0` was a typo (err, 2 typos); I intended `nargs='*'`. You are correct about my workaround:  it messes up the help/error text from argparse. I guess the best approach for my case is as you suggest: drop `choices`; validate the way our ancestors did!