# Optional positional argument, that only accepts values from a specified list

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm rewriting a legacy C program in Python 3, using argparse. The program takes zero, one or more positional arguments, that have to be from a specified list. Let's say the possible values are 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' and 'E', for simplicity's sake. There are no other arguments in the legacy program, and I don't expect them in the new version. But you never know. :-)

If I add the argument without choices, like this:

```
p.add_argument("action", help = "What to do", nargs='*')
```

It works perfectly, I can supply zero, one or more of that argument.

But if I specify the choice list, like this:

```
p.add_argument("action", help = "What to do", choices=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], nargs='*')
```

I can no longer specify zero arguments. I get this error:

> error: argument action: invalid choice: [] (choose from 'A', 'B', 'C',
> 'D', 'E')

Is there any way to be able to add an argument that will accept zero, one or more arguments from a specified list?

Comment: At https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70370597/argparse-how-to-configure-multiple-choice-multiple-value-optional-argument I explain why `*` choices has this issue.  The simplest fix is to change the argument to flagged, '--action'.

Comment: @hpaulj : Normally I would have converted this into a flagged argument, but in this case, because I'm rewriting legacy code, I need the new code to be a drop-in replacement. And changing how this argument works would break a lot of other code, so that's unfortunately not an option in this case.

Comment: A `C` program probably uses a simpler parser like `getopt`, which just returns 'positionals' as an unparsed list.

Comment: @hpaulj The program is hand-parsing the command line, so to speak. While the program could be old enough to predate getopt, I don't think it is. Never the less the command line parsing code is all specific to this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `add_argument` method once for each option in your list, supplying the whole list as possible choices for each argument, and then use the '?' for the `nargs` field

for example here:

```
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(sys.argv[0])
choices = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
for i, choice in enumerate(choices):
    parser.add_argument(choice, metavar=choice, 
                        help="Help Message For Choice" + choice, 
                        choices=choices, nargs='?')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

This will accept 0, 1, 2, ... `len(choices)` arguments.  You will probably want to override the usage string if you go this route.

`python3 name_of_pythonfile.py -h`

```
usage: name_of_pythonfile.py [-h] [A] [B] [C] [D] [E]

positional arguments:
  A           Help Message for ChoiceA
  B           Help Message for ChoiceB
  C           Help Message for ChoiceC
  D           Help Message for ChoiceD
  E           Help Message for ChoiceE

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

To override the default usage message you just need to pass a string to the usage keyword argument in the ArgumentParser constructor.

```
parser = ArgumentParser(prog, usage="My New Usage String")
```

[argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse)

Comment: This could work. Since repeating a value wouldn't make sense in this case, there shouldn't be a need for more arguments than the number of choices. *fingers crossed* I would probably just name them without the value ("arg" + str(i)), since that would make them easier to iterate through.

I have never tried overriding the usage string, or the full help, but I'm sure I can google that. :-)

Comment: @jbang  I updated the answer to include how to override usage string

Comment: @Alexander Thank you. Next step is figuring out how to fix the --help output. The solution you have provided does break some of the automatic things in argparse, but it's the only solution that will give me what I need, so I'll take it. And thank you for the solution.

The obvious solution to overriding -h/--help, is to set add_help = False and add my own -h/--help argument. But I want to look into keeping the internal argument and just overriding the output. If for no other reason than it could be fun to try.

Comment: @jbang  That part is easy too.  See the updated code and the output it produces in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is an out-of-the-box way to achieve this but you can always do the check yourself:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("action", help="What to do", nargs='*')
cli_args = parser.parse_args([])  # no arguments
valid_choices = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
for arg in cli_args.action:
    if arg not in valid_choices:
        parser.error(f"argument action: invalid choice: "
                     f"'{arg}' (choose from {sorted(valid_choices)})")

print(cli_args.action)
```

This outputs

```
[]
```

And the following outputs for different arguments:

```
cli_args = parser.parse_args(['A'])
...
['A']
```

```
cli_args = parser.parse_args(['A', 'B'])
...
['A', 'B']
```

```
cli_args = parser.parse_args(['A', 'B', 'Z'])
...
usage: main.py [-h] [action [action ...]]
main.py: error: argument action: invalid choice: 'Z' (choose from ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

Comment: That's true, but I would really like to avoid having to do the check myself, so I'll hold out for a little while, before writing the check. :-)